# Availability Calendars - change amount of months shown to visitor

Tags: 7

I need to make some changes to a website that is using the 'Availability Calendars' module(available on https://drupal.org/project/availability_calendars ).

On the website a calender is shown to the visiting person that highlights any available date for 2014. I now need to have the months for 2015 to show up in the calender too.

But I can't find the option to make 2015 visible for the visitors. Using google I found this: http://drupalcode.org/project/availability_calendars.git/blob/273d12c0ad811341615197a8601797f3003f52e9:/README.txt

It says "Choose the global settings for the availability calendars under Administer -> Site configuration -> Availability calendars. You can choose how many months will be shown for each node and whether or not to display the calendars on the node page itself".

But when I go to "nl/admin/config/content/availability-calendar" I only can set the 'labels' and add a css-class to those labels. There is a link to "nl/admin/config/content/availability-calendar/styling" but that only has options to set the font-weight,color, font-size, etc...

I then went to look in the content types ( under 'Structure --> content types') but the option isn't showing up there either.

So the problem is I need to change the amount of months shown to the user (who is not logged it) on the front-end of the site for 2014 and 2015. But I can't find any option to change the amount of months shown. Can anyone point me in the correct direction? Or do I need a different module to do this? If so what module would I need for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I just needed to enable the 'Field UI' module. So basicly I did this to solve my problem:

- Enable to 'Field UI'  module
- Go through to "Structure --> content types"
- Go to the 'Manage display' tab